# Xcode was crashed after adding ART.xcodeproj into Library

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I'm developing an app with React Native.

Xcode was crashed after adding ART.xcodeproj into Library.

Here is the version information:  **Version 9.0 beta 4 (9M189t)**

Some **crashed logs** are below:

```
Process:               Xcode [7810]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               9.0 (13213.5)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-13213005000000000~15
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [7810]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2017-08-30 15:50:49.870 +0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12.6 (16G29)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        *

Sleep/Wake UUID:       *

Time Awake Since Boot: 15000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       12000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Illegal instruction: 4
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x4
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 9M189t

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
```

Device Information

```
Model: MacBookAir7,2, BootROM MBA71.0166.B30, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 1.6 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.27f2
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 6000, Intel HD Graphics 6000, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4B3445364533303445452D45474345000000
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4B3445364533303445452D45474345000000
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x117), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.171.130.1a1)
Bluetooth: Version 5.0.5f1, 3 services, 17 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0128G, 121.33 GB
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: iPhone
USB Device: Barcode Reader
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Air, Apple Inc., 27.2
```

Any idea ? Thanks a lot ahead : )

Comment: were you able to start Xcode project again or is it crashing every time?

Comment: @BünyaminBennyGenel   m able to start the project again, and it works well , only crashed while adding external library to Libraries.

Comment: I think this is a problem about that you are using a beta version of Xcode and not related to react-native. Maybe you should submit the crash log to Apple.

Comment: @BünyaminBennyGenel  Here I make a video, you could have a look if convenient. [xcode-crashed-record](https://github.com/cikai/disk/blob/master/xcode-crashed-record.mov?raw=true)  : )

Comment: I don't know much about it but ART library might be already included to the project because its a react-native library and the crash might be because of that