# SDK compiled with xcode 9 does not work fine in xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, ios11

I've an SDK that I built with Xcode-9-Beta. However, I'm trying to use this framework in a project that's running Xcode 8.3.3. However, I get a build error which says, `ld framework not found "FileProvider" for architecture x86_64`

Now, this `FileProvider` has been introduced in iOS-11 and I'm not using it anywhere in the SDK code. What could be the possible error. Please comment if you need further data around this.

Comment: This one has been fixed by Apple.Use Xcode 9.1

Answer (score 2):

**FileProvide framework is only available in Xcode 9.**

You need to download and install Xcode 9 manually and copy the FileProvider framework from Xcode 9 to the same directory of Xcode 8 if you want to continue working on Xcode 8 environment.

1. Download the Xcode9 release version [here](https://developer.apple.com/download/).
2. Go to

   > /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/

You can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46483043/1371949).

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps

1) Add FileProvider.framework in Link Binary With Library section in Build Phase.

2) Make it Optional in place of Required.

3) Clean the project.

4) Run.

Application will run without crash.

Answer (score 1):

I run into this bug, too.

I think this might be a Xcode bug, I have already filed a bug report.

If you want to solve this, you can add FileProvider.framework into your target's linked frameworks and libraries, and select status to optional.

this will solve this error, but any function related to Fileprovider will not work.