# ld: framework not found FileProvider for architecture x86_64 in Xcode 8.3.2

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, macos

I am getting suddenly the following error in my Xcode 8.3.2 if I try to add some other framework like pod 'Firebase/Database' by pods
and not able to compile the project.

I have downloaded few thirdparty apps like google plus, Facebook, twitter, etc by pod file. And thats working fine. But, I am trying to add one more framework into pods, its installing fine, but while trying to run the project getting following error while compile time.

> ld: framework not found FileProvider for architecture x86_64 clang:
>   error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

Even I tried with following answer, but could not helped me to fix.

[xcode 8.3 framework not found FileProvider for architecture armv7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45994854/xcode-8-3-framework-not-found-fileprovider-for-architecture-armv7)

I am trying this from 2 days, still not got any solution, can any one give suggestions to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Im going to follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45994854/xcode-8-3-framework-not-found-fileprovider-for-architecture-armv7 solution r u sure its not working>?

Comment: Yes, its not working, so that, I mentioned here. Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

xcode 8.3 does not have the @"FileProvide" Framework because one the pods you installed is using this framework.
Solution - update your Xcode to latest version (9.0.1) and  you are sorted.

Comment: Its happening while I am trying to install any new framework. And whether it is Firebase or some other framework this issue happening, else its compiling fine.